# Triangle partial length of hypotenuse

Tags: geometry, triangle

How can I solve for X?

What I did was solve for C, and then took (6/6+2)*C. It seems to work but I am not completely sure. Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: What is it that leaves you unsatisfied with what you've done so far?

Comment: And: why (given that you are "not completely sure") did you do that particular calculation rather than some other?

Comment: I guess it works but I am not capable of formulating a proof. Was also wondering if there were any alternative formulas to use.

Comment: It's all I could think of....I'm not a math genius, hence why I am here.

Comment: I think you shouldn't be thinking in terms of "what formula can I find that will solve this?" but in terms of "what do I know about triangles in general, and this particular triangle, that will help?". So first of all you found C (you didn't say how, but there's an obvious way which I guess you used). Very sensible. But then why -- I'm not looking for a *formalized proof* but for *any kind of explanation* -- the particular calculation you did next?

Comment: I'm aware that this sort of questioning can sound hostile, so let me be as clear as I can that (1) it's not meant to be and (2) asking "why did you do X?" is *not* a coded way of saying "you shouldn't have done X".

Comment: Are the lengths of the vertical parts 6 and 2? I couldn't see it very well

Comment: I think they are, yes.

Comment: @amikic  I think question needs to be reformatted again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ,

> Both outer and inner triangles are similar (AAA similarity) Therefore , $\frac{6}{6+2} = \frac{x}{7}$ . i.e., x = $\frac{21}{4}$.